# saving matrix of numbers in binary text file and reload it matlab

Tags: matlab

Given a matrix M of intiger numbers, the perpose of the whole process is to save the matrix M to a binary text file called TM.txt,than reload the TM.txt file to read the matrix M and apply some processes over.

```
M= [1 2 3 4 5;

4 5 6 7 8;

4 6 8 9 9;

8 9 7 6 4]
```

i did save the M matrix to a binary text file using:

```
fileID=fopen('Tm.txt','w');
fwrite(fileID,M);
fclose(fileID);
```

i reload the file using the command :

```
fileID = fopen('Tm.txt');
M= fread(fileID);
```

but the result was like:

```
M =
1
5
6
7
8
4
5
6
7
8
4
6
8
9
9
8
9
7
6
4
```

any ideas ?

Comment: maybe `load` and `save`?

Answer (score 0):

To save data I would use as an option:

```
dlmwrite('TM.txt',M,'\t');
```

To load from the text file there are bunch of options. One of them:

```
importdata('TM.txt')
```

Just in case here you can read [more](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) and [even more](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)

Comment: the perpos is to save it as a binary text file than read again from the text file, any information ?

Answer (score 0):

Using fwrite write binary data to a file, it does not create a text file.  If you write a binary file using fwrite, you need to use a binary read using fread.

Using dlmwrite, as suggested by madbitloman writes a text file.  The '\t' separates the values written by the tab character.  This can then be read by textscan.

Binary files take less memory to store your values, but are not easily understood by opening in a text editor.  Text files take up more space to save the same numbers but are easy to read in a text editor.

Comment: the memory is very important to me so i need to save the matrix as a binary text file, the problem is in reloading the file and reading from it, the martix become in another form. si any idea ?